# Java Create XML using XPath

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have list of xpath expressions and associated values in a database.

With this data I have to create a Xml document.

Example of data in database:

```
Value             XPath
------     ------------------------------
Jhon         /root/user/name
USA          /root/user/address[@Type='Present']/country
India        /root/user/address[@Type='Permanent']/country
Male         /root/user/gender
```

Example Xml output:

```
<root>
  <user>
    <name>Jhon</name>
    <address Type="Present">
        <country>USA</country>
    </address>
    <address Type="Permanent">
        <country>India</country>
    </address>
    <gender>Male</gender>
  </user>
</root>
```

Which is the best approach?. 
Is there an API or library to help me solve this?

Otherwise logic which will satisfy the requirement.

Please suggest. I tried with Java example and not able to create the xml using xpath.

Comment: I'm not sure there's even a consistent way to do this. How would such a system handle something a set of XPaths like `/a[@Attr='a1']`, `/a[@Attr='a2']`, `/a/b`

Comment: I would suggest `Node`, `Document`, and file stream to create, write, and edit to XML. `XPath` is mainly used for identify and navigate nodes in XML document and contain about 200 built-in functions that also include node manipulation.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bmchild/6285705

Comment: @Luis, the code which is there in github is not working... Test it at your end.

Comment: Well, it should at least give you ideas on how to handle this. Not sure if you will find a ready to use solution.

Comment: I have seen that example already. Just want to know, by finding the xpath using each level of node, if the node is not exists it has to be created. Thinking whether that would be a best approach.